# What is a Research Scientist position?

Tags: postdocs, job, faculty-application

In an advert, I read:
"[University U] is inviting applications for a multi-year fully funded Post-Doctoral Associate position. Highly qualified candidates may also be considered for a Research Scientist position."

What is a Research Scientist compare to a Post-Doctoral Associate position in an USA Academic like environment ?

Answer (score 5):

Every university is different. However, my university (UT Austin) has, roughly, three research-only track positions: Research Associate, Research Scientist, and Research Professor. None of them are tenure-track or require teaching, and they all are roughly equivalent to the tenure-track positions: Assistant Professor, Associate Professor, Professor. Research Scientist has roughly the same promotion requirements as Associate Professor but only requires 3 outside letters rather than 8, and is a little lighter than the research and service requirements to the best of my knowledge. Both tracks can be proceeded by a postdoc position, but often do not. I started at UT as a Research Associate straight out of my PhD program and was later promoted to Research Scientist.

These positions are offered to give the university a place for professional researchers in non-teaching roles to work without the constraints or requirements of a teaching job. We have lots of them only mostly grant/soft money at the computing center where I work.

Comment: You're right, of course, that every university uses at least slightly different terminology.  I'm a bit surprised that UT has a nontenure track position called "Research Professor".  That seems to invite confusion.  On the other hand I once held a position called "Research Assistant Professor"...which was a part-time postdoctoral position.  So maybe the moral is that you never know what these titles really mean.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, it is confusing, and AFAIK, there aren't a ton of them at UT. UT System's Handbook of Operating Procedures defines these things and is public. It's still hard to sort it all out. Presumably one could change tracks along the way if one wanted the benefits (and responsibilities) of tenure. I think that mostly the Research track is used outside of departments and in other units that don't teach or grant degrees.